# nginx proxy_pass works only for root path

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I want to setup nginx as a reverse proxy for apache. I have apache on port 8080. It works only for the root path, for example https://www.example.com, but it won't work for https://www.example.com/index.html

```
   location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

    }
```

I tried adding slash to the address, like http://127.0.0.1:8080/ but then I got config error. Something like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662940/nginx-proxy-pass-cannot-have-uri-part-in-location  I tried to use the rewrite, but I don't know what should this rewrite be.

Comment: You should remove the `try_files` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below for nginx reverse proxy

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```